# Create walls in a game from a random maze

Tags: c#, game

I use four `bool`s, if `true` a wall is in that direction:

```
bool top = true;
bool bottom = true;
bool left = true;
bool right = true;
```

Then I work through the four and create a wall for each:

```
//Create Walls
        if (top)
        {
            GameObject myWallSelection = WallSectionTop[Random.Range(0, WallSectionTop.Count)];
            var myWall = Instantiate(myWallSelection, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
            myWall.transform.parent = GameObject.Find("LevelDesign").transform;
        }

        if (bottom)
        {
            GameObject myWallSelection = WallSectionBottom[Random.Range(0, WallSectionBottom.Count)];
            var myWall = Instantiate(myWallSelection, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
            myWall.transform.parent = GameObject.Find("LevelDesign").transform;
        }

        if (left)
        {
            GameObject myWallSelection = WallSectionLeft[Random.Range(0, WallSectionLeft.Count)];
            var myWall = Instantiate(myWallSelection, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
            myWall.transform.parent = GameObject.Find("LevelDesign").transform;
        }

        if (right)
        {
            GameObject myWallSelection = WallSectionRight[Random.Range(0, WallSectionRight.Count)];
            var myWall = Instantiate(myWallSelection, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
            myWall.transform.parent = GameObject.Find("LevelDesign").transform;
        }
```

How can I optimise this code and remove duplication?

Comment: You could do each block in one loop for however many boolean orientation matches you get

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. What does the rest of your function look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While Peter Csala's answer starts off well, I personally find that it goes off the rails halfway through and overcomplicates things; but I was following him at the start, so this answer will start from the same point: **identify the differences**.

Each of the four blocks has the same pattern:

```
GameObject myWallSelection = {THE_DIFFERENCE}[Random.Range(0, {THE_DIFFERENCE}.Count)];
var myWall = Instantiate(myWallSelection, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
myWall.transform.parent = GameObject.Find("LevelDesign").transform;
```

Straight off the bat, we can see that the second and third line are never any different. They will clearly be moved in the common logic.

When we look at the first line, the only difference is in the choice of the collection that you're using. In all cases, you're really just picking a random element from the chosen collection.

**The only difference is the collection**. This immediately suggests that we can abstract this method, and that the only parameter is the collection.

```
private void DoStuff(GameObject[] myCollection)
{
    //
}
```

`DoStuff` is a terrible name; you should improve this based on what makes sense in the current context. The question doesn't reveal enough context for me to appropriately name it.

The logic here is simple enough that you can simply copy/paste your code and make sure to refer to `myCollection` (again, `myCollection` should be renamed by you).

```
private void DoStuff(IEnumerable<GameObject> myCollection)
{
    GameObject myWallSelection = myCollection[Random.Range(0, myCollection.Count)];
        var myWall = Instantiate(myWallSelection, transform.position, 
    Quaternion.identity);
    myWall.transform.parent = GameObject.Find("LevelDesign").transform;
}
```

Your original code then simple has to choose the appropriate collection and call this method:

```
if (top)
    DoStuff(WallSectionTop);

if (bottom)
    DoStuff(WallSectionBottom);

if (left)
    DoStuff(WallSectionLeft);

if (right)
    DoStuff(WallSectionRight);
```

I disagree with the additional part of Peter's answer to introduce a mapping list. Not that it can't be done, but that it obfuscates the code more than it should, especially with the tuple being added into the mix.

**If** the variables weren't individually defined, I would agree. For example, if instead of four boolean values, you had an enum to decide the direction; then the additional mapping would make more sense as the individual directions wouldn't be individually listed in the code.

But if you're going with predefined booleans, which the question presupposes, then keeping the handling of each boolean separate yields the best readability.

---

For good measure, I think the random selection logic should be abstracted into a method of its own, simply because it would be much more readable when someone wants to understand what `DoStuff` does.

This random selection can be abstracted generically and added as an extension method to `IEnumerable<T>`:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> SelectRandomElement<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection)
    {
        return collection[Random.Range(0, collection.Count)]
    }
}
```

This improves the readability for `DoStuff`, because now the reader doesn't have to figure out the random selection logic to understand that a random item is being selected:

```
private void DoStuff(IEnumerable<GameObject> myCollection)
{
    GameObject myWallSelection = myCollection.SelectRandomElement();
    var myWall = Instantiate(myWallSelection, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
    myWall.transform.parent = GameObject.Find("LevelDesign").transform;
}
```

Comment: Your reasoning seems valid that mapping might be an overkill in this particular case. BTW in your `SelectRandomElement` the collection does not have a `Count` property. The linq's `Count` method could be used there but it might iterate through the whole collection just to return the number of items.

Answer (score 2):

In order to minimize repetitive code you have to understand what are the common parts of each branch and what are the differences.

In your particular case I can spot only one difference:

```
GameObject myWallSelection = {THE_DIFFERENCE}[Random.Range(0, {THE_DIFFERENCE}.Count)];
```

#### First iteration

So, extracting the common part into a method and then passing the varying part(s) as parameter(s) can significantly reduce the repetitiveness of your code

```
private void PerformTheCommonPart(List<GameObject> source)
{
    GameObject myWallSelection = source[Random.Range(0, source.Count)];
    var myWall = Instantiate(myWallSelection, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
    myWall.transform.parent = GameObject.Find("LevelDesign").transform;
}
```

- Your question does not detail your domain, I can not suggest a good name for this method
- Your question does not provide information about the type of the `WallSectionTop` and other collections, I assumed they are `List<GameObject>`

  - So we can perform the index operator (`[]`) call and the get for the `Count` property

The reduced code looks like this:

```
if (top)
{
    PerformTheCommonPart(WallSectionTop);
}

if (bottom)
{
    PerformTheCommonPart(WallSectionBottom);
}

if (left)
{
    PerformTheCommonPart(WallSectionLeft);
}

if (right)
{
    PerformTheCommonPart(WallSectionRight);
}
```

#### Second iteration

While the core functionality has been extracted, the main code is still repetitive.

In order to avoid this we can define a mapping between conditions and collections:

```
List<(Func<bool> shouldPerform, List<GameObject> source)> mapping = new List<(Func<bool>, List<GameObject>)>
{
    (() => top, WallSectionTop),
    (() => bottom, WallSectionBottom),
    (() => left, WallSectionLeft),
    (() => right, WallSectionRight),
};
```

- In this example I've used `ValueTuple`s but you can simply use `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>` as well
- It is important to define the condition as a function since you want to evaluate the current value of the given `bool` variable when we iterate through the collection

With this in our hand the final code will look like this:

```
foreach (var map in mapping)
{
    if (map.shouldPerform())
        PerformTheCommonPart(map.source);
}
```

Or with Linq:

```
mapping.ForEach(map => map.shouldPerform(), map => PerformTheCommonPart(map.source));
```